# ScrollViewReader not scrolling programmatically

Tags: list, forms, swiftui, scrollview

I have the following view and I'm attempting to have it scroll to the bottom on button click as elements are added to the list. I've searched and found that ScrollViewReader is the option to use however my implementation doesn't appear to be working.

My attempts at fixing have included explicitly setting the id of the cell on both the inner views as well as the outer `HStack{}` I even attempted to set the id to a reference of itself, kind of knowing that's a bad idea, but for brevity. I also removed any extra views inside of the list such as `HStack{}`, `Spacer()`, etc.. and just left my `ColorsChosenView().id(i)` thinking that extra views might cause it, but I digress the issue still persists.

```
var body: some View {
            VStack {
                ScrollViewReader { reader in
                    List {
                        ForEach(0..<vm.guesses.count, id: \.self) { i in
                            HStack{
                                Spacer()
                                ColorsChosenView(locationCorrect: 1,
                                                 locationIncorrect: 3,
                                                 color1: vm.guesses[i][0],
                                                 color2: vm.guesses[i][1], 
                                                 color3: vm.guesses[i][2], 
                                                 color4: vm.guesses[i][3])
                                Spacer()
                            }.id(i)
                        }
                    }.listStyle(InsetListStyle())

                    Divider()
                        .frame(maxWidth: 250)

                    ColorChoicePicker(vm: vm)

                    Divider()
                        .frame(maxWidth: 250)

                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        FABButton(text: "SUBMIT")
                            .onTapGesture {
                                vm.submit()
                                reader.scrollTo(vm.guesses.count - 1)
                            }

                    }.padding()
                }
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .onAppear(perform: {
                vm.resetGame()
            })
    }
```

To simplify things, I found that this works just fine. Yet my implementation doesn't feel much different.

```
var body: some View {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                VStack {
                    Button("Jump to #50") {
                        proxy.scrollTo(50)
                    }

                    List(0..<100, id: \.self) { i in
                        Text("Example \(i)")
                        .id(i)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It would've been really useful to have the broken code as a "working example", the reason the other code works, is because you identify a row by the index it has, while the first one is identified by the object itself

Comment: I wanted to do that but I don't know what's causing it. I tried to "Dumb it down" but every time I did, it worked. LOL

Comment: Ok. Now I'm stumped. The exact implementation you have now works for me. The issue might be within your vm-object.

Does the submit() function change the `guesses` variable by any chance? Cause I tried making an ObservableObject and whenever I change the variable, and then scroll it doesn't work

Comment: the submit function simply adds the guesses to an array which is then populated to the list.

Comment: Aha. there's the culprit, you're modifying the array in the background and scroll in the foreground. I've edited my answer and provided 2 solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're modifying the array, this should work:

1: call the function in the main thread (`DispatchQueue.main.async`)

-> this will "kinda" work, it will scroll but not to the current but the previous last item

2: (Workaround) handle scrolling in a change-handler (you could also remove the `shouldScroll` variable if all changes should make it scroll to the bottom)

```
class NumbersContainer: ObservableObject {
    @Published var numbers: [Int] = Array(0..<25)
    
    func submit() {
        self.numbers.append(self.numbers.count)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var nc = NumbersContainer()
    @State var shouldScroll: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollViewReader { reader in
                Button("Submit", action: {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        nc.submit()
                    }
                    self.shouldScroll = true
                })
                
                List {
                    ForEach(0..<nc.numbers.count, id: \.self) { i in
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("Row \(i)")
                            Spacer()
                        }.id(i)
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: nc.numbers) { newValue in
                    if shouldScroll {
                        reader.scrollTo(newValue.count - 1)
                        shouldScroll = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another Possibility would be to use the ScrollReaderProxy as a parameter of the submit function:

```
class NumbersContainer: ObservableObject {
    @Published var numbers: [Int] = Array(0..<25)
    
    func submit(reader: ScrollViewProxy) {
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        dispatchGroup.enter() // All leaves must have an enter
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.numbers.append(self.numbers.count)
            dispatchGroup.leave() // Notifies the DispatchGroup
        }
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            reader.scrollTo(self.numbers.count - 1)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var nc = NumbersContainer()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollViewReader { reader in
                Button("Submit", action: {
                    nc.submit(reader: reader)
                })
                
                List {
                    ForEach(0..<nc.numbers.count, id: \.self) { i in
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("Row \(i)")
                            Spacer()
                        }.id(i)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm setting the ID to an ID of the enumerated value of count. It should be the index based on my code. If I had set the ID to `T<Guess>` then sure, but it's set to `T<Int>` aka index of.

Comment: Oh, nvm then I'm an idiot... :D

I think I've found the issue, I'll change the answer

Comment: I figured the binding would keep it updated correctly. Fantastic, it's working great now.

Comment: Yeah, I had a similar issue once, nearly drove me mad. :D